# Backup Exec VM Agent or Veeam?

Tags: vmware-esx, restore, vmware-vsphere

We currently use Backup Exec to backup our physical servers. We are implementing vSphere 4 soon. I was wondering if it's better to just use the VM agent for BE or go with Veeam and use BE + the application agents within the VMs. Is one preferred over the other? Which one would be faster to backup? Restore? Any opinions and suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're currently going through this debate ourselves at my company. Before Backup Exec 2010, I would have said that Veeam was the better solution. However, I went to Symantec's launch event a couple weeks ago, and came away fairly impressed. From what I could tell, Backup Exec's VMware Virtual Infrastructure agent does everything that Veeam does, and has a couple additional features.

In particular, single pass backup for Exchange, SQL Server, and Active Directory (SharePoint will be added later). The other thing that was nice to hear at the event was that they were reducing the price of the VMware by half to $1595 MSRP (per server). That's brings it in line with Veeam for dual-socket systems. However, there's an additional $2000 charge for the data de-duplication option for Backup Exec (single charge across the whole environment).

Right now, I'm just focused on getting us upgraded to vSphere 4. Once that's underway, I'll run evals of both Veeam and Backup Exec, and see how I like each one.

Answer (score 0):

All those BackupExec "extras" add up quick. Of course I'm biased, I work for Veeam. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

To me Veeam is no brainer, unless you are willing to pay a few times more for much less functionality.

Don't forget that besides host license mentioned above (by the way, it is 
$1,863.76 according to Symantec web-site), you will also need to buy actual BackupExec server licenses, as well as SAN Shared Storage Option (SSO) license for each host.

Answer (score 0):

At this present time I am liking Veeam B&R V5 a lot more than the BE Agent for BE 2010 R2.  The source deduplication cuts my backup time in half for full backups.

The fact Veeam allows you to do granular restore on AD/SQL/Exchange with the Enterpise licensing, and not a $1500 "Agent" **per VM per SERVICE** is another good reason to chose Veeam over BE's AVVI Agent.  If you have a couple SQL servers, an Exchange Server and so on and you don't already have the appropriate licenses for that you're VMWare backup budget just grew substantially.

Of course, that's only a concern if money is a motivator.  I don't know a boss out there today that wouldn't consider cost though.